# iOS 13 UIPrinter quickly goes out of existence

Tags: swift, uipickerview, ios13, uiprintinteractioncntrler

User selects a printer (UIPrinter) using the UIPrinterPickerController.  Once selected, that UIPrinter is used for output (print(to:) throughout the app and persists for subsequent launches of the app.  From iOS 9 through iOS 12, this method has worked well.

However, under iOS 13, the following happens:

The UIPrinter is always available when used for the *first* time.  But once used, after a short period of time (less than a minute) the UIPrinter seems to go out to existence.  This happens when using the Xcode Printer Simulator or an actual physical printer via AirPrint.

Here's the Xcode Console message on the first print - it works:

```
Simulated\032Color\032Laser\032@\032myMac._ipps._tcp.local.: Print-Job successful with warning: Job attributes did not match print document.
```

```
Simulated\032Color\032Laser\032@\032myMac._ipps._tcp.local.: Release-Job successful with warning: successful-ok (successful-ok)
```

Here's what happens 1 minute later:

```
Simulated\032Color\032Laser\032@\032myMac._ipps._tcp.local.: Print-Job failed: Printer "Simulated_Color_Laser_myMac" does not exist.
```

When this happens, the only way to continue is to re-select the UIPrinter in the PrinterPicker.

Any ideas as to what might be happening here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in iOS version 13.4 released 3/24/2020.